# How to replace the icon of my menu when it is open?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How to replace the icon of my menu when it is open?

Here is my page, this is the left menu :

https://www.s1biose.com/boutique/ma-boutique-pro

I added the following code in a JS file of my theme, but it does not work :

```
  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(this).find('.navbar-toggle-first svg').removeClass("fa-bars").addClass("fa-times");
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(this).find('.navbar-toggle-first svg').removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-bars");
  });
```

Here is the code of my menu :

```
<a class="navbar-toggle-first-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-first">
  <span class="navbar-toggle-first collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-first">
    <span class="fa-layers fa-3x">
      <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-bars" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use on the click event:

```
$('selector').click(function(){
        $(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');  
});
```

I suggest add a function example:

```
<span id="mySpan" onclick="myFunction();"></span>
<script> function myFunction(){//here do the change} </script>
```

[complete Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/10/)